# Jenkins cannot start after disk restored from snapshot

Tags: jenkins, google-compute-engine, devops, gcloud, snapshot

This Jenkins installation is running on a GCE since the beginning of 2020, pipelines, plugins and other configurations are working without issue.

After a day of experimenting with it to introduce some new OS-level additional features that should have taken 5 minutes and ended up taking the whole day, I realized I was hitting a wall and decided to clean the board by deleting the VM and creating a new one using a snapshot taken back in november, last time the VM was properly working without modification. This particular Jenkins installation is used to build staging version of our internal applications so I wasn't that concerned with downtime and such.

After creating a new VM, same specifications of the previous one, running Debian 10, and assigning the snapshot as source for the disk and went to reload the dashboard and got surprised with this:

[image]

Logging in the vm itself I find that everything directory/file wise is there but running `sudo systemctl status jenkins` returns this:

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-01-05 17:54:55 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 653 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=7)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service

Jan 05 17:52:34 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Jan 05 17:52:40 jenkins-1-vm jenkins[653]: Correct java version found
Jan 05 17:52:41 jenkins-1-vm su[767]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Jan 05 17:52:41 jenkins-1-vm su[767]: + ??? root:jenkins
Jan 05 17:52:41 jenkins-1-vm su[767]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Jan 05 17:54:55 jenkins-1-vm jenkins[653]: Starting Jenkins Automation Server: jenkins failed!
Jan 05 17:54:55 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7
Jan 05 17:54:55 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
Jan 05 17:54:55 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 05 17:54:55 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I started searching on google, basically spending the last 2 hours on this, and found nothing relevant apart a lot of articles mentioning using Java8 which cannot be applying to this case as java is there and the log itself says `Correct java version found`.

As a last attempt I tried to `apt purge jenkins` and reinstall it and after that everything works but, of course, everything is also wiped out. So I created another vm and before attempting anything else, decided to ask here for help.

Is there something in Jenkins that could not being brought over in a snapshot of the disk and cause this terrible `Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.` message? What can I try to fix this and restore it?

Adding more information: Trying to launch jenkins via the `.war` file (`java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war`) works but start it as if it's a new installation, asking for an admin password and all the rest, ignoring the existing `config.xml` and all the rest already present in `/var/lib/jenkins`.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar experience with Jenkins running on a GCE VM. I have not finished solving the problem, but I have managed to get Jenkins running without reconfiguring everything again.

After stepping through the start-up script over a few hours I found a spot where it disappeared into a hole and came back as a failure. By looking at the steps after the failure I was able to get the system going again from first principles.

The commands I ended up running (and should really stick in a script because my Jenkins instance will not start after a system reboot with the same fingerprint you are getting). This is a Debian 10 system running in GCE.

```
. /etc/default/jenkins
DAEMON_ARGS="--name=$NAME --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME --output=$JENKINS_LOG --pidfile=$PIDFILE"
DAEMON=/usr/bin/daemon
SU=/bin/su
JAVA=`type -p java`
$SU -l $JENKINS_USER --shell=/bin/bash -c "$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -- $JAVA $JAVA_ARGS -jar $JENKINS_WAR $JENKINS_ARGS"
```

At this point Jenkins is running and answers to my web browser call.

Comment: Well... thanks to Stackoverflow not notifying of anything unless I come back to the website I missed this answer. In the meanwhile I rebuilt a new VM from scratch and luckily I managed to recover the jobs from the snapshot I've had. I'll try and run this script in a controlled "disaster" to see if it all works. Thanks!